# Unable to load ngStorage module in my app

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to pass in ngStorage as a dependency to my module. Please can you advise what could be the issue

Below is my bower dependency

```
     "dependencies": {
     "angular": "1.5.7", 
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.0",
    "angular-ui-grid": "3.2.1",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.19.1",
    "lodash": "4.13.1",
    "devextreme": "16.2.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    **"ngstorage": "0.3.10"**
  },
```

**app.module.js**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.elcy', [
    'dx'
]);


angular.module('app.entities', [
    'dx',
    'ngStorage'
]);

angular.module('app', [
    'ui.bootstrap.contextMenu',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'app.entities',
    'app.elcy',
    'ngStorage'
])
```

## Error Trace

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module refdata due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module refdata.legalentity due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngStorage due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngStorage' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=ngStorage
    at http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8199/ui/vendor/angular/angular.js:2075:17
```

Comment: Do you load the resource `ngstorage/ngStorage.js` ?

Comment: Have you included it in index.html?

Comment: Ah, my bad I did not include it in index.html. Thanks a ton, works now!